# Cannot assign value, Swift treat is as immutable

Tags: swift

I have protocol:

```
protocol CellLineDrawing : Any {
    var isShouldDrawBottomLine : Bool { get set  }
    var isShouldDrawUpperLine : Bool { get set }
}
```

Then i try to set value to objects that conform to protocol:

```
var arrValues : [Any]!


func drawLinesIfNeeded () -> Void {

    guard arrValues!.count > 0 else {
        print("Empty array")
        return
    }

    guard arrValues!.first is CellLineDrawing else {
        print("Does not conform to cell line drawing protocol")
        return
    }

    var firstModel = arrValues.first
    var lastModel = arrValues.last

    (firstModel as! CellLineDrawing).isShouldDrawUpperLine = true //ERROR - Cannot assign to immutable expression of type 'Bool'




}
```

Comment: @MartinR all we should know elements is of type Any and does conform to protocol

Comment: Do you have a really good reason for using `[Any]!` here? (it probably shouldn't be an implicitly unwrapped optional for starters). Can you really put *anything* into it? Looks like you just want a [`CellLineDrawing`].

Comment: @Hamish i dont want to explicitly set type of object, that was my point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The expression `(firstModel as! CellLineDrawing)` is a *constant,*
and you cannot mutate its properties (unless it is an instance of 
a reference type).

Unless I am mistaken, you need a temporary variable:

```
if var firstModel = arrValues.first as? CellLineDrawing {
    firstModel.isShouldDrawUpperLine = true
    arrValues[0] = firstModel
}
```

Comment: thanks but why is it constant? Same syntax in Obj-C will work well.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban: What is your "same syntax" in Objective-C? Are you sure that you are not dealing with references?

Comment: i mean round brackets, which i use to cast object.

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban: In Objective-C you probably have an NSArray, and its elements are *objects,* i.e. reference types.

Comment: you mean anything i put in round brackets in swift is immutable?

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban: Not generally. But `firstModel as! CellLineDrawing` is an immutable expression. It creates a new value of type CellLineDrawing.

Comment: i thought i create Any object (mutable, because it var) that is conform to protocol CellLineDrawing

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban: It's *properties* are variable, but that does not help if you have a constant *value.*

Answer (score 2):

Your assignment can only work if `firstModel` is the instance of a class *and* Swift knows that it is the instance of a class.

If your `firstModel` is always the instance of a class, then you can make your code work by changing the protocol.

Because your protocol is not marked with `class`, Swift thinks it can be applied to a `struct` or a `class`.  So `(firstModel as! CellLineDrawing)` is treated as immutable because it would be if the item is a struct.

By adding `class` to your protocol:

```
protocol CellLineDrawing : class, Any {
    var isShouldDrawBottomLine : Bool { get set  }
    var isShouldDrawUpperLine : Bool { get set }
}
```

you tell Swift that this protocol can only be applied to an object instance.  In that case, the item can be mutated.

```
(firstModel as! CellLineDrawing).isShouldDrawUpperLine = true // this now works
```

---

If your `firstModel` can be the instance of a `struct`, then you will have to make a mutable copy of the item, change it, and then copy it back.  See [@MartinR's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45236142/1630618).

Comment: @vacawama thanks for help but that does not solve the problem, feel free to try it in playground and check by yourself

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban: *If* the actual instances are reference types then this should solve your problem as well (that's why I had suggested it in a now deleted comment)

Comment: Is "Any" is supposed to be reference type or named type?

Comment: @EvgeniyKleban, is `firstModel` the instance of a `class` or a `struct`?

Comment: @vacawama struct

Comment: OK, since you have structs, then your only alternative is to update a copy of the struct and then assign it back which is exactly what @MartinR is doing in his answer.